# Swift : Codable Struct Always Nil

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I Have the following JSON Response

```
{
    "status_code": 1000,
    "data": {
        "user_id": 1000,
        "bid": "E5PPD5E3",
        "province": 0,
        "location": "123,123"
    },
    "message": "Verified"
}
```

And This is my Struct

```
struct Basicresponse : Codable{

    var statusCode : Int!
    var message : String?
    var data : data?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case statusCode = "status_code"

    }

}

struct data : Codable{

      var province : Int
      var userID : Int
      var location : String
      var bid : String

      enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

            case province, location , bid
            case userID = "user_id"

          }
  }
```

And

```
 do {


  let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Basicresponse.self, from: data!)

         if(jsonData.statusCode == 1000){

                print(jsonData)
         }else{
                 self.alert.show(target: self.view, message: jsonData.message!)
          }


            }
 catch let jsonerr {
          print("error serrializing error",jsonerr)
 }
```

But the result as below,

```
Basicresponse(statusCode: Optional(2000), message: nil, data: nil)
```

I don't know why both the data and the message are always nil ?! I tried the end point with Post man and its works fine but in my app its always nil, Am i missing something here ?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What did you use for API call? Alamofire or URLSession

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you’ve excluded `message` and `data` from your `CodingKeys`. But you can add them like so:

```
struct Basicresponse: Codable {
    var statusCode : Int!
    var message : String?
    var data : data?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statusCode = "status_code"
        case message, data
    }
}
```

---

The other alternative is to not supply `CodingKeys` at all and tell your decoder to do the snake case conversion for you.

```
let data = """
{
    "status_code": 1000,
    "data": {
        "user_id": 1000,
        "bid": "E5PPD5E3",
        "province": 0,
        "location": "123,123"
    },
    "message": "Verified"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct BasicResponse: Codable {
    var statusCode: Int
    var message: String?
    var data: Bid?
}

struct Bid: Codable {
    var province: Int
    var userId: Int
    var location: String
    var bid: String
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let jsonData = try decoder.decode(BasicResponse.self, from: data)

    if jsonData.statusCode == 1000 {
        print(jsonData)
    } else {
        print(jsonData.message ?? "No message")
    }
} catch let jsonError {
    print("error serializing error", jsonError)
}
```

I hope you don’t mind, but I’ve renamed your `data` type to be `Bid` (as `data` doesn’t conform to standard class naming conventions of starting with upper case letter and it’s too easily confused with the existing `Data` type). I don’t know if `Bid` is the right name, so use whatever you think is appropriate, but hopefully it illustrates the idea.

Comment: Thanks Rob, As you mentioned I was excluded the message and the data properties all fixed now